# Not understanding steps in derivation for entropy of a Gaussian random variable

Tags: entropy

Can someone explain the last two steps in the derivation given below?

This is the derivation of the entropy of a Gaussian random variable:

[image]

Comment: As for the last step, $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{ln}(e)$ and $\mathrm{ln}(a)+\mathrm{ln}(b)=\mathrm{ln}(ab)$. But I think you should show some more effort, other than just pasting a link. Do you have any ideas of your own? And if not, can you at least state the problem more elaboratly, because nowhere have you specified what $\phi$, $\mu$, $\sigma$ etc. are....

Comment: The answer can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906538/simple-algebra-clarification-needed-for-gaussian-entropy-formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that  the expectation of a constant is equal to the constant it self, and the expectation is linear operator so 
$$ -E[-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{ 2\sigma^2}-\ln{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}]=\frac{1}{ 2\sigma^2}E[(x-\mu)^2] + \frac{1}{2} \ln{{2 \pi \sigma^2}}$$
Recall also that $\ln(a^b)=b \ln(a)$ for $a$ non negative,  $\ln(e)=1$, and  $\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$.  Moreover,  $E[(x-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2 $, then  $$\frac{1}{ 2\sigma^2}E[(x-\mu)^2] + \frac{1}{2} \ln{{2 \pi \sigma^2}}= \frac{1}{ 2\sigma^2}\sigma^2 + \frac{1}{2} \ln{{2 \pi \sigma^2}}= \frac{1}{ 2}+\frac{1}{2} \ln{{2 \pi \sigma^2}}= \frac{1}{ 2}\ln(e)+\frac{1}{2} \ln{{2 \pi \sigma^2}} =  \frac{1}{ 2}\ln{{2e \pi \sigma^2}}$$