# Two closed-form analytical solutions for multivariate Gaussian entropy: How are they equal?

Tags: statistics, information-theory, covariance, entropy, gaussian

Entropy of a multivariate Normal distribution is well-known to be

$$H(\boldsymbol{X}) = \frac{N}{2}\ln2\pi e\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}\sigma_i^2\right)^\frac{1}{N}$$

but [here](https://sgfin.github.io/2017/03/11/Deriving-the-information-entropy-of-the-multivariate-gaussian/), it is also shown to equal

$$H(\boldsymbol{X})  =\frac{N}{2}\ln\left(2\pi e\right)+\frac{1}{2}\ln\det(\Sigma)$$
where $\Sigma$ is the sample covariance matrix.

How to show that the two formulas equate to each other? and which is more of the complete simplification of multivariate Gaussian entropy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $X=AZ$ where $A$ is a constant matrix and $Z$ is standard Normal distributed, $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)$. In this case, the covariance of $X$ is $\Sigma$. It results: $$\det\Sigma=\sigma_1^2(A) \sigma_2^2(A) \cdots \sigma_n^2(A)=\det(AA^T).$$

The derivation is as follows:

\begin{align} h(X) 
& = \frac{N}{2}\log \left(2\pi e\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}\sigma_i^2\right)^\frac{1}{N}\right)\\
& = \frac{N}{2}\log \left(2\pi e\right) + \frac{N}{2}\log \left(\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}\sigma_i^2\right)^\frac{1}{N}\right)\\
& = \frac{N}{2}\log \left(2\pi e\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log \left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}\sigma_i^2\right)\\
& = \frac{N}{2}\log \left(2\pi e\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log \det\Sigma.
\end{align}

It is more common to write the second one. It is even more common to put the first term inside the second one as follows:
$$ h(X) = \frac{1}{2}\log\det(2\pi e\Sigma). $$

Comment: Why is the $+\frac{1}{2}\ln\det(\Sigma)$ alone as a second term though. plus there is an exponent $\frac{1}{N}$. could you show a derivation between the two formulas instead

Comment: I rephrased it. I think that what's happening in your case is what I wrote above. In your first equation, everything is inside the log.

Comment: thanks. could you show how the formulas shown in the question reduce to the new formula you've introduced, line by line?

Comment: To reply to your comment directly, split the logarithm in two terms and use the relation on $\det\Sigma$ that I wrote. To be sure that the derivation is correct, you should tell us what the $\sigma_i$'s are.

Comment: $\sigma^2$s are just the variances along the diagonal of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$

Comment: Oh! I interpreted them as singular values! Is the covariance matrix diagonal in that case? If yes, then the determinant is the product of the elements on the diagonal.

Comment: I tested the equality $\det\Sigma=\sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2 \dots $ in python by generating trivariate Normal data and computing their covariance matrix, but the LHS and RHS don't equal

Comment: They are equal if and only if $\Sigma$ is diagonal, namely the components are independent. In my derivation above, the $\sigma_i$'s are the singular values of $A$. In case of a diagonal $A$, then they coincide with the standard deviations, but it's not the general case. Your first equation is only true if the covariance is diagonal, not in general. Your second equation is true in general.

Comment: the variables used are empirically non-i.i.d. If by diagonal, you mean $0$s for off-diagonals, no, there is always covariance between the variables empirically

Comment: When you " put the first term inside the second one", where did the $N$ go. wish I could see the steps in between

Comment: If the variables are not independent, I am afraid that the first relation that you wrote is not true. As for the $N$, notice that $2\pi e$ goes inside the $det$. Therefore, we are taking the determinant of $2\pi e \Sigma$. In general, given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, it results $\det(aA) = a^n \det(A)$.

Comment: Separate question: $H(\boldsymbol X)$ explodes as expected when the number of variables $N$ increases. How should multivariate entropy be normalized from its $(0,\infty)$ range to $(0,1)$?

Comment: Well, it depends on the variances as well. The differential entropy scales as O(N), so if you divide by $N$, at least you know that it doesn't “explode”. However, to be normalized, you need to take into account the variances. You can apply Hadamard inequality and discover that your first relation is an upper bound of your second relation, but you can't obtain any stricter bound (because if $\Sigma$ is diagonal, your second relation is equal to the first one).

Comment: there is no textbook answer for normalized multivariate entropy? and you say divide by $N$, even though univariate entropy is normalized by dividing by $\log N$

Comment: It really depends on what do you mean with “univariate entropy”. If you fix the variance, you can normalize; otherwise, not. The differential entropy of a Gaussian distribution goes to infinity as $\sigma\to\infty$.

Comment: what do you think of the analytical solution to joint entropy: \begin{align}
h(X, Y)&=\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi e)^{2}|K|\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi e)^{2} \sigma^{4}\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)
\end{align} https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914831/joint-entropy-closed-form-analytical-solution