# Joint Entropy closed-form analytical solution

Tags: statistics, logarithms, information-theory, entropy, gaussian

**Differential entropy** of a single Gaussian random variable is

$$H(X) = \frac{1}{2} \ln (2\pi e \sigma^2)$$

What then is the closed-form analytical solution for **joint entropy**, $H(X,Y)$?

Comment: Do you mean the joint entropy of a multivariate Gaussian? See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Differential_entropy), or a textbook like Cover and Thomas. In fact, if you understand the derivation of the one-dimensional case, you should be able to derive this yourself.

Comment: By the way - it seems that you have asked four questions in quick succession that are all about slightly different aspects of the same thing. In no case have you provided your thoughts on the question, or discussed what you have read. I personally don't think this is productive - if you're running into repeated issues with one concept, you should at least carefully read the standard textbook regarding this, and tell us about what you didn't understand in their treatment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X, Y) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, K),$ where
$$
K=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma^{2} & \rho \sigma^{2} \\
\rho \sigma^{2} & \sigma^{2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Then **differential entropy** is $$h(X)=h(Y)=\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi e) \sigma^{2}$$ and **joint entropy** is

\begin{align}
h(X, Y)&=\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi e)^{2}|K|\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi e)^{2} \sigma^{4}\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: why are the covariance terms in $K$ equal to $\rho \sigma^2$ instead of $\rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y$? Is this solution assuming $\sigma_X = \sigma_Y$ and why would anyone assume that?

Comment: This is a question about modeling. It is, essentially, the simplest model of correlation. As you said, the general form is another though.

Comment: someone asked the exact same question as me here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914899/derivation-of-mutual-informations-closed-form-analytical-solution/3916589?noredirect=1#comment8081487_3916589