# Simple algebra clarification needed for Gaussian entropy formula

Tags: logarithms, information-theory, substitution, entropy, gaussian

Norwich (2003) gives the following equality based on a substitution as shown in the image.
[image]

I don't get it though because $\frac{1}{2}$ appears in two places in the first formula. Does the substitution written occur at both places? Even if I do this, I don't know how to distribute the multiplication of "$\ln e$"

Could someone show the steps in-between involving the substitution, and how to arrive at the final equation shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac12\ln(2\pi\sigma^2) + \frac12 = \frac12\ln(2\pi\sigma^2) + \frac12\ln e\\
= \frac12\left(\ln(2\pi\sigma^2) + \ln e\right)\\
= \frac12\ln(2\pi e\sigma^2)
$$
It is the ${}+\frac12$ on the right side that gets an extra factor of $\ln e$. Then we use distribution, and finally elementary logarithm rules to put the two logarithms together into one.

Comment: ok so the substitution is only for the second place not the first, and $\ln e = 1$. Does $e \sigma^2 = e^{\sigma^2}$? Because I've seen it used as well. which one is right?

Comment: $e$ multiplied by $\sigma^2$ is _not_ the same as $e$ raised to the power of $\sigma^2$.